# Trouble Designing an Adder that works with register in Logisim

Tags: digital-logic, logisim

I have designed three different modules in Logisim: Half adder, full adder, 4-bit adder below is the implementation of each of them (I am not allowed to use the program's Arithmetic folder).
[image: half adder]
[image: full adder]
[image: 4-bit adder]

My question is that when I use the 4-bit adder with two 4 bit inputs-both of pin types- It works perfectly fine, but when I use a register's output as the adder's input, The program generates errors like the image below. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how can I solve this problem? Why is it just showing the lowest 2 bits as an error? Thanks in advance for your help.
[image: 4-bit adder not connecting to register]
[image: 4-bit adder connecting to register]

Comment: Probably because you have 4 bit lines driving a single flip-flop at its input.

Comment: @MituRaj It's a register and not a flip-flop and it also has 4 data bits

Comment: Are you sure about it? Is it level sensitive or edge triggered?

Comment: @MituRaj Yes absolutely. It's positive edge triggered.

Comment: So where's the reset/clear to the register? Is it active low?

Comment: The reset is shown in the last picture and is meant to be connected to from a control function outside of the module. Everything is turned off. It's actually a 4-bit Sequence counter.

Comment: What's that little blue pin under the D input on your FF?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's a register and that is the enable input. when not connected, Logisim treats it as connected and set it to 1

Comment: Have you tried the same thing in [Digital](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital)? Maybe it's a quirk in Logisim.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Not actually cause it is part of a project I must design in Logisim so I have no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Everyone and thank you for your opinions. Apparently, the problem was that I was using the Logisim for too many hours(16 hours) and constantly making new modules and running simulations so it had trouble simulating all of them. I just closed it and opened it again and the problem was gone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you worked out your own answer. Though I have to say that's a first for my use of the program. I'll have to keep it in mind, just in case. (I use others, now, though: Logisim Evolution and Neeman's Digital.)

Comment: Yes, of course, there are better options out there but as I said it's a university project and I must use Logisim.

Comment: Sounds fine, then. Problem solved. You are allowed to select your own answer, if you care to. You've written out what solved your problem here. A reason you might consider for doing so, otherwise, is that it will keep others from accidentally imagining they might also write an answer that helps. Saves the time of others who might not read everything before saying something. Just FYI.

Comment: I tried to, but the website won't allow me till tomorrow. I'll do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Interesting. Yet another weird detail about the site. Best wishes regarding the rest of your lesson work. But judging from your work so far, I think you are doing very well and will continue to do so. I'm very much hoping that you keep at it and succeed well in life!!

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing works fine for me in Logisim. No errors.

The fact that you see "00EE" means to me that two bits are, in fact, "00". But that two other bits aren't.

I can't tell you exactly where the error is, from your pictures. In general, though, I think this often occurs something you think is an input pin is actually an output pin. The program makes it way too easy to create a pin that looks like an input pin (because of its east/west selection) but is really an output pin (because it says output: yes.) On the schematic, you can't tell. You have to look at the properties, to know for sure.

In any case, I easily replicated your work above and did not get any errors.

I recommend that you go through each of your added circuits, one by one, and click on each input and each output and verify that they are inputs and outputs as you expect. I believe you will catch the error if you do that.

Anyway, here's a sample that is close to yours, where I've clocked it a few times:

[image]

Comment: I designed it carefully so I am completely sure that every component is what it must be and double-checked again. Thanks for your opinion.